# My custom ViewGroup doesn't scroll inside a ScrollView

Tags: java, android, scrollview, flowlayout

I've extended ViewGroup to achieve something like a FlowLayout.  I put my custom ViewGroup into a ScrollView, dynamically add a bunch of content and it doesn't scroll.  The content that flows off the screen is not viewable.

What am I missing, how can I allow my ViewGroup to be compatible with ScrollView?

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewGroup should have its height set to wrap_content to work properly. This also means you need to implement onMeasure() properly to give your ViewGroup an appropriate height.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar.  I extended AdapterView to create a linear layout that is backed by data.  When I put the widget inside of a scrollview, I cannot scroll to contents.  The scrollview's height is only as big as the screen.  What exactly does onMeasure do that will solve this problem?